# Port from Jetty Server instance

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I am writing a service discovery application which will register web applications on a zookeeper node. One of the attribute is the port number on which service is available. In code I got the handle of jetty server instance but how can I find the port number from a Jetty Server instance ?

Answer (score 0):

Walk the connectors, and ask them for their registered host names (so you know what network interfaces they are listening on) and local ports (that they are bound to).

Here's a template you can start with.

```java
    for (Connector connector : server.getConnectors())
    {
        if (connector instanceof NetworkConnector)
        {
            // we have a network capable connector
            NetworkConnector networkConnector = (NetworkConnector) connector;
            // What interface?
            String interfaceName = networkConnector.getHost();
            // What local port is it bound to?
            int localPort = networkConnector.getLocalPort();
            // What is the declared protocol default for this connector?
            String defaultProtocol = networkConnector.getDefaultConnectionFactory().getProtocol();
            // What other features does this connector handle?
            for (ConnectionFactory connectionFactory : networkConnector.getConnectionFactories())
            {
                // List of protocols handled by this specific connection factory for this specific connector
                connectionFactory.getProtocols();

                if (connectionFactory instanceof SslConnectionFactory)
                {
                    // this can handle TLS/SSL based connections
                }

                if (connectionFactory instanceof HttpConnectionFactory)
                {
                    // this can handle http protocols

                    // get the http specific configuration
                    HttpConfiguration httpConfig = ((HttpConnectionFactory) connectionFactory).getHttpConfiguration();
                    // what port is recognized as secure
                    httpConfig.getSecurePort();
                    // what scheme is recognized as secure
                    httpConfig.getSecureScheme();
                }

                if (connectionFactory instanceof HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory)
                {
                    // can handle encrypted http/2 protocols (and alpn features)
                }

                if (connectionFactory instanceof HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory)
                {
                    // this can handle http/2's special clear-text "h2c" protocol (no alpn features)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```